# What is the default order of Directory Enumerate/Get methods?

Tags: c#, file, sorting, directory

I understand that you *can* sort them as needed, but is there a specified default sorting order for the return values of the following methods?

```
EnumerateDirectories();
EnumerateFiles();
GetDirectories();
GetFiles();
```

Comment: Does it not state in MSDN? Have you tried? Is it based on the folders sort order?

Comment: The docs for GteFiles say "The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort method if a specific sort order is required."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it's documented. It depend on the version of .NET or the version of the operating system. Because of that, you should sort it yourself.